# Does Rust implicitly create map entries when indexing, like C++?

Tags: c++, rust, hashmap

In C++ the indexing operator is defined for `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` so that if your reference to the container is non-const just the act of indexing without assigning is enough to have implicitly created a value inside the container. This sometimes creates subtle bugs, where you expect to be referencing a value inside a container but instead actually create one, e.g. `config["stting"]` instead of `config["setting"]`.

I know Python addresses this by having `__setitem__` and `__getitem__` be separate methods but this requires cooperation with the parser.

Does Rust do anything to address this frequent source of bugs?

Comment: Some would call that a *feature*, not a bug.

Comment: It’s definitely a feature: Although there’s no direct concept of getters and setters, C++ could easily have implemented the Python behaviour. I have to assume the choice to do it differently was conscious. That said, the C++ `map` API is certainly easy to use incorrectly and thus not ideal.

Comment: Interesting feature.  For C++ you can use the [at()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) method.  It excepts if the key is not available.  Not sure it is really a source of bugs unless you don't understand that it is happening.  The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) states that this is how it works.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Working with a large team of mixed skill level, it becomes clear very quickly it is not a feature, especially when it is combined with implicit inserts causing iterator invalidation. Python distinguishing dictionary (what you want in many cases) versus default dictionary (has the C++ behavior, which admittedly can be handy) is a better way to handle this, or Rust borrow checking protecting you against invalidation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No Rust doesn't have that problem. There's no implicit creation of items in Rust collections.

For example you'd insert a key-value pair to a `std::collections::HashMap` with `map.insert(key, value)` and retrieve a value with `let value = map.get(key);`.

Note that `.get()` will return an `Option<&V>`, so if the key didn't exist you will get `None` as a result.

Rust also offers an easy way to either retrieve a value or to insert some default value for the given key if the value doesn't exist with:

```
let value = map.entry(key).or_insert(0);
```

`HashMap` also [implements the `Index` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#impl-Index%3C%26%27_%20Q%3E), which allows retrieval of  a value with `let value = map[key];`, which will panic if `key` doesn't exist in `map`.

Note that because `HashMap` does not implement `IndexMut`, this `[ ]` bracket syntax always returns an immutable reference to the value, so you cannot insert or modify values this way.

Comment: Well, the creation in C++ is not really implicit either... I mean, `operator[]` is specifically used when you want to create an item if it doesn't exist, so it's not much different than, say, `Vec::resize_default` which inserts `Default` values for the items created...

Comment: True, but OP used the word implicit in his question to refer to the C++ way, so I just used that also.

Comment: @MatthieuM `operator[]` in practice is usually used even when people don't want to insert the item because it's much less verbose than the alternative, and because of it being the way to do it in other languages. Also most of the time it will appear to do what you want, so it takes newbies a long time to realize. Especially if the first time they ever run into it is because of an iterator invalidation issue.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: Sure. C++ was first, though, so it's hard to blame it for behaving differently when it was the other languages which broke precedence :/

Comment: @MatthieuM I can blame it for making the error prone use the less verbose one, or for it just being a bad design choice to not make it a separate operation -- it's not efficient to default construct then copy assign either. Nobody is on trial and we have the benefit of hindsight, but I think it's safe to say now it's not the best design.

Comment: @JosephGarvin: I can definitely agree on the default construct+assign part :)